# Соблюдение отступов при верстке

Tags: html, css

Я только начал учиться верстать поэтому наткнулся на непреодолимую проблему. Когда пытаюсь поставить картинку на нужное место она никак не изменяет свое положение(я уже использовал все виды margin и обнулял pading но получается только если margin поставить в минус).Прошу подсказать юному подавану.(кстати position: absolute; тоже не помогает)

```
byke{
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 122px;
    margin-top: 112px;
}`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: А код можно? Просто как-то тяжело гадать что у тебя там написано. А так используй контейнер для сайта и верстай при помощи флексов) И не будет проблем и позионированием элементов

Answer (score 0):

Возможно мой вариант, вам поможет. Также советую ознакомиться с display:flex - https://doka.guide/css/display/

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center; /*  Выравнивает по оси X  */
  align-items: center; /*  Выравнивает по оси Y  */
  width:600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img    src="http://service.volkswagen.ru/eshop/uploads//items/41a889f37ea187065638053d0fb3d316e28c6261.jpg" alt="Велосипед">  
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, познакомился  недавно с display:flex, стало гораздо легче